# Launch Python script from command line w/ `bindkey` and import clipboard contents

Tags: terminal, copy-paste, zsh

Is it possible to launch a terminal command with a shortcut of type <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + [LETTER]?

My aim is to use the current content of the clipboard (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and use an available letter (for example <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) to launch some python script (I only need to know how to launch a terminal command, since a Python script can be launched from there and, I guess, also the retrieving of the clipboard content can be made).

So basically I'm looking for a global keybinding to run

```
python3 my_script CONTENT_OF_CLIPBOARD
```

Comment: Is this on macOS? And if yes, are you maybe confusing Control and Command key here?

Comment: Also, does this need to be a shortcut within Terminal or a global one? What would be the content of the clipboard in that moment, which command do you want to execute?

Comment: @nohillside of course it is command (edited) ; but it wouldn't be that problematic if I had to use another key.

Comment: @nohillside If i have copied the content of some text in the clipboard, I would like a global command who will allow me to launch a command in the terminal, with the clipboard content : for instance "python3 my_script CONTENT_OF_THE_CLIPBOARD"

Comment: Do you want to do this from `zsh` or `bash`?

Comment: @Seamus zsh, since I guess this the default on the terminal

Comment: OK - I'll make a suggestion if you don't mind... There are Q&A *related* to yours on U&L SE. This [one in particular](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79897/how-can-i-use-bindkey-to-run-a-script) seems appropriate - but I'm not sure I actually understand your Q. If it's not relevant to your Q, perhaps it will help you formulate a better question? Oh - one piece that's missing from the Q&A cited is the *system command* `pbpaste`. That can probably be used in your Python script.

Comment: Define what you mean by _launch a terminal command_: It could mean that you have a terminal command line open, and by pressing some hotkey, you want to run a certain command. It could also mean that you don't have a terminal open, and by pressing some hotkey, you want your terminal program to open and execute a certain command.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not quite clear on what you're trying to accomplish, but perhaps this will help:

##### 1. You didn't post a Python script, so I made one up: `mypyapp.py`.

Apologies, I'm not a PyGuy! I saved it as `~/scripts/mypyapp.py`. All it does is grab the contents of the pasteboard, and print it to `stdio`. You can augment it, or put the relevant code in your script:

```py
#!/opt/local/bin/python3
import sys, subprocess

def get_clipboard_data():
    p = subprocess.Popen(["pbpaste"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    retcode = p.wait()
    data = p.stdout.read()
    return data

new_data = get_clipboard_data()

print('clipboard data: ',new_data)
```

##### 2. Make the script executable:

```shell
chmod 755 ~/scripts/mypyapp.py
```

*Note: You can run this script from the command line to test it before proceeding*; ***make sure*** you copy a line of text using <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> before running the script - otherwise the pasteboard may be empty!:

```shell
~/path/to/mypyapp.py
```

##### 3. Enter this line in your zsh config file - `~/.zshrc`:

```shell
bindkey -s '\eg' '~/scripts/mypyapp.py^M'
```

##### 4. `source` your `~/.zshrc` file as shown below to load the revised config file into your shell:

```shell
. ~/.zshrc

# alternatively, use the command 'source ~/.zshrc'
```

##### 5. Run `bindkey` to verify it's been added:

```shell
bindkey | grep mypyapp

# which should yield one line:

"^[g" "~/scripts/mypyapp.py^M"
```

*Note that the keyboard shortcut **is not** what we entered in Step 3. `'\eg'` was expected to mean <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>. But it seems that macos has overruled that choice, replacing it with `^[g`; which is translated as follows:

<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>

The sequence is a bit *tricky*; you must press both <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>, then release both, and then finally <kbd>g</kbd>.

##### That's it

I didn't test this thoroughly, so make sure you do before committing it to to a serious application. Also know that adding some `zle` (zsh line editor) code gives you many more options, but this may be a reasonable place to start. Let us know if you hit any snags, or have further questions.