# Running Python script with a keyboard shortcut in automator

Tags: automator, python

I've written an auto mouse clicker script in Python that clicks on chosen parts of my screen when the script is run. I'd like to be able to do this quickly and repeatedly so want to be able to run it with a keyboard shortcut. Automator seems the best way to do this but I can't figure out how not being very familiar with how it all works. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/452346/119271